# What will happen if two computers having same MAC address and same IP address in the network?

Tags: windows, ip-address, mac-address

What will happen if two computers on the network are having same MAC and IP address? Assume 20 to 25 computers are present in the network and they are accessing the internet through single gateway. Is any security risk there for both the computers which are having same MAC and IP? In this scenario HTTPS connection is secure or not? Can traffic of one computer monitored by other?

Comment: The whole point about MAC addresses is that they are unique, so unless you deliberately spoof a duplicate MAC this cannot happen. If two nodes in a network have the same IP neither will connect if the other is also connected.

Comment: @AHF MAC addresses are recycled, so it is possible to have duplicate MACs on a network. It's extremely rare, but it is possible. My old networking professor had it happen to her while in the Army. They had a crazy connectivity issue that they could never figure out and it ended up being duplicate MACs.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you have duplicate IP addresses on a network, your computer will give you a warning that the IP you are using is already in use. When two devices somehow wind up with the same IP address, this is detected and the network interface on both on them gets disabled, causing each system to lose its connectivity until the conflict is resolved.

You can refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/462178/duplicate-mac-address-on-the-same-lan-possible) for the duplicate MAC situation.